# Javascript iPhone code to download and save image in iphone memory from server

Tags: javascript, iphone

What is the way to download and save image in iPhone memory from server in javascript??
Is it possible??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new image element in the DOM. As you can add an onload event to the image just replace it when the the event is fired.

Comment: i actually don't understand.....can u give me sample code or refer me to some tutorial??